# Android Hardware Acceleration: do I need Hardware Layer for animations?

Tags: android, animation, hardware-acceleration

Just a simple question.

I have been reading some documentations in order to provide a very smooth UI. I know that by default, any applications projects targeting SDK 14+ will have Hardware Acceleration turned ON.

In this case, do I really need to use Hardware Layers for specific animations that modifies the properties (alpha, scale, translation and rotation) that are optimized as part of Project Butter ?

I know these layers, if correctly used, are to optimize the rendering process by "pre-buffering" the animations frames and storing them into the GPU memory. But when should I use them ? Are they really necessary ?
Or does Hardware Acceleration do it for you ?

Thanks for your inputs !

Answer (score 0):

I have been curious about this as well so I did a little test. I turned on show hardware layers updates and ran a simple saturation animation along with a translate and it didn't light up. So I ran it with `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE` and sure enough it lit up. So I guess it does play a part. It didn't really make a big difference for the animation on my Nexus 5x though.

Comment: Can you define your saturation animation ? For me I also made a small test I could see no difference with a simple 10 seconds long animate() that animates scale and translation values on both axis of the HelloWorld textview in a new project. I tested in on a Galaxy Note 3 running CM 13. I could clearly see some loss of frames every now and then in the GPU monitors: it's not smooth-perfect. Why ?

Comment: Saturation animation is basically changing an `ImageView`s color filter using `animatedView.setColorFilter()`.

Comment: So it's not part of the optimized properties ? Those properties are modified inside the RenderThread introduced in Lolliopop. It helps relieving the UI Thread of too many tasks.